# Rails client_side_validations inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, client-side-validation

I'm trying to add the gem `client_side_validations` to my application. It works pretty fine if I go to something like `controller/new`, but, inside a bootstrap modal, it simply does nothing.

I inspected the HTML and it does not add the `data-validate` attribute. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Post the code in your modal.

Comment: Is the default bootstrap modal code, with the form render inside it without the layout, and the forms is the default simple_form code (I also add client_side_validations_simple_form and client_side_validations_turbolinks).

Comment: You should be using SimpleForm and SimpleForm's Bootstrap integration. From there you can use client_side_validations-simple_form which supports Twitter Bootstrap..

see this article [simple form and client-side-validation](http://www.ddarrensmith.com/blog/2012/05/17/ruby-on-rails-client-side-validation-with-validation-helpers-and-twitter-bootstrap/)

Comment: it work's outside a modal, just doesn't work inside the modal..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just figured it out. In my coffeescript call, I do something like:

```
$('.modal').on 'shown', ->
    $(this).find('input:visible:first').focus().end().find('form').enableClientSideValidations()
```

This focus the first visible input, and enable the client side validations on the form.

Comment: using `shown.bs.modal` instead of `shown` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did not work for me however the following did! Not sure why but if you find the same as me it might be your answer...

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function () { $(ClientSideValidations.selectors.forms).validate(); });
```